# Javascript Snake Game unexpected End of input Error

Tags: javascript

I am a Javascript beginner, and right now we have to write a Javascript Snake Game for school, where it displays a death message when you die.

You die when you touch the snake itself or the walls. You get points for each apple you eat.

It should also make a sound when you die and a sound when you eat an apple (this is my main problem).

I tried many YouTube tutorials and stuff I found on here and also stuff I found on other websites on the internet, but nothing seems to work really.

I also think it doesn't work properly that the game counts when you ate an apple. Please help me, no one in our course knows how to do it, probably because we are chemical engineers and don't know much about programming, especially programming in Javascript.

Here is the code:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Set the dimensions of the canvas
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;

// Set the size of each cell in the grid
const cellSize = 20;

// Set the initial position and direction of the snake
let x = 0;
let y = 0;
let dx = 1;
let dy = 0;

// Set the initial length of the snake
let length = 5;

// Set the initial position of the apple
let appleX = 10;
let appleY = 10;

// Set the score to 0
let score = 0;

// Create an array to store the positions of the snake's body
const body = [];

// Create the audio elements for the death and eating sounds
const deathSound = new Audio('death.mp3');
const eatSound = new Audio('eat.mp3');

// Draw the grid lines on the canvas
function drawGrid() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= canvas.width; i += cellSize) {
    ctx.moveTo(i, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(i, canvas.height);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i <= canvas.height; i += cellSize) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, i);
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, i);
  }
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#ccc';
  ctx.stroke();
}

// Draw the snake on the canvas
function drawSnake() {
  // Shift the first element off the array and add the new position to the end
  body.shift();
  body.push({ x, y });

  // Draw each cell of the snake's body
  for (let i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
    ctx.fillStyle = (i === body.length - 1) ? 'green' : 'white';
    ctx.fillRect(body[i].x, body[i].y, cellSize, cellSize);
  }
}

// Draw the apple on the canvas
function drawApple() {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(appleX, appleY, cellSize, cellSize);
}

// Move the snake and check for collision with the walls or itself
function moveSnake() {
  // Update the position of the snake
  x += dx * cellSize;
  y += dy * cellSize;

  // Check if the snake has collided with a wall
  if (x < 0 || x >= canvas.width || y < 0 || y >= canvas.height) {
    deathSound.play();
    alert('You died! Your score was: ' + score);
    return;
  }

  // Check if the snake has collided with itself
  for (let i = 0; i < body.length - 1; i++) {
    if (x === body[i].x && y === body[i].y) {
      deathSound.play();
      alert('You died! Your score was: ' + score);
      return;
    }
  }
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: It looks like `moveSnake` function lacks the closing curly brace. If your real code does have it, another source of the said error is passing an empty string to `JSON.parse`, your example doesn't seem to use that method, though. How is p5.js related to the question?

Comment: Thank you very much, i wouldn't have seen that. But I don't think that's the only problem in the code. Do you see any other errors?

Comment: Where do you call the different functions? Can you please also paste the corresponding HTML here?

Comment: I don't have corresponding HTML, i wrote all that in p5js, the online editor and everything worked at first, but then when i started to implement the sound it didn't work

Comment: Ok now I get it. Make attention that p5js is not vanilla JavaScript. Simple said:  p5js is a library which makes use of JavaScript. Do you need to write the Game in p5js or in vanilla Javascript? 
To play sounds in P5js --> https://p5js.org/examples/sound-load-and-play-sound.html
To play sounds in JS    --> https://gomakethings.com/how-to-play-a-sound-with-javascript/

Comment: Thank you very much, that explains my confusion. We have to write the game in p5js. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Check this out, I guess that the sounds you have can not be found. Check what is logged to the browser console. With a sound from another Website, it works. Also I've added a setInterval to call all the functions

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      // Set the dimensions of the canvas
      canvas.width = 500;
      canvas.height = 500;

      // Set the size of each cell in the grid
      const cellSize = 20;

      // Set the initial position and direction of the snake
      let x = 0;
      let y = 0;
      let dx = 1;
      let dy = 0;

      // Set the initial length of the snake
      let length = 5;

      // Set the initial position of the apple
      let appleX = 10;
      let appleY = 10;

      // Set the score to 0
      let score = 0;

      // Create an array to store the positions of the snake's body
      const body = [];

      // Create the audio elements for the death and eating sounds
      const deathSound = new Audio('death.mp3');
      const eatSound = new Audio('eat.mp3');

      const pepsi = new Audio(
        'https://www.freesoundslibrary.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/ding-ding-sound-effect.mp3'
      );

      // Draw the grid lines on the canvas
      function drawGrid() {
        for (let i = 0; i <= canvas.width; i += cellSize) {
          ctx.moveTo(i, 0);
          ctx.lineTo(i, canvas.height);
        }
        for (let i = 0; i <= canvas.height; i += cellSize) {
          ctx.moveTo(0, i);
          ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, i);
        }
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#ccc';
        ctx.stroke();
      }

      // Draw the snake on the canvas
      function drawSnake() {
        // Shift the first element off the array and add the new position to the end
        body.shift();
        body.push({ x, y });

        // Draw each cell of the snake's body
        for (let i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
          ctx.fillStyle = i === body.length - 1 ? 'green' : 'white';
          ctx.fillRect(body[i].x, body[i].y, cellSize, cellSize);
        }
      }

      // Draw the apple on the canvas
      function drawApple() {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fillRect(appleX, appleY, cellSize, cellSize);
      }

      // Move the snake and check for collision with the walls or itself
      function moveSnake() {
        // Update the position of the snake
        x += dx * cellSize;
        y += dy * cellSize;

        // Check if the snake has collided with a wall
        if (x < 0 || x >= canvas.width || y < 0 || y >= canvas.height) {
          deathSound.play();
          // alert('You died! Your score was: ' + score);
          canvas.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
          pepsi.play();
          return;
          swda;
        }

        // Check if the snake has collided with itself
        for (let i = 0; i < body.length - 1; i++) {
          if (x === body[i].x && y === body[i].y) {
            deathSound.play();
            // alert('You died! Your score was: ' + score);
            canvas.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
            pepsi.play();
            return;
          }
        }
      }

      function draw() {
        drawGrid();

        drawSnake();
        moveSnake();
        drawApple();
      }

      setInterval(function () {
        draw();
      }, 500);
```

```css
canvas {
        border: 1px solid green;
      }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="100" width="100"></canvas>
```